# how to add text area when i select any option from select option

Tags: jquery, html

I have one condition where I want to add text area when I select any option from select option. I have 4 to 5 options in my select box and I want one text area to be added when I select any option from my select box.

Here is my html:

```
<select name="menu-114" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
   <option value="Select Category" selected="selected">Select Agent Name</option>
   <option value="Option 1">Mr. abc</option>
   <option value="Option 2">Mr. abc</option>
   <option value="Option 3">Mr. abc</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
```

I want to add the textarea when I select any option from above select box.

See my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4yt5p7s/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o4yt5p7s/4/ here is what i am asking

Comment: Are you trying to copy something into the `textarea` or to add an actual `textarea` to the DOM?

Comment: i want to add textarea when i select any option, yes actual textarea to the DOM..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think why you would want to but here's how I would do it:

Listen for the `change` event on your `select` element and use [`$.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/)

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=menu-114]', function(){
    $("<textarea>").appendTo(".agent_select_wrap");
    //$(this).val() will return the value attribute of the select
});
```

Here's a **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o4yt5p7s/5/)**